# Removing duplicate observations with dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This is a followup to a previous question where I the previous solution does not appear to work for a more complex dataset.
Previous question:
[Filter out observations present in specific pairs of samples in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077756/filter-out-observations-present-in-specific-pairs-of-samples-in-r#46077909)

I am trying to filter a dataset to exclude rows where there are duplicate observations in specific pairs of samples.

The new dataset contains many different pairs of related samples

```
sample observation1 observation2
sample1A 10 x
sample1A 15 y
sample1A 20 x
sample1B 7 h
sample1B 15 a
sample1B 22 s
sample2A 10 g
sample2A 11 g
sample2A 14 g
sample2A 20 h
sample2B 10 a
sample2B 30 t
sample2B 40 a
sample2B 50 h
```

In the example above I need to exclude the rows where observation1 is identical for sample1A compared to sample 1B and also for sample2A compared to sample 2B (and so on for many more pairs of samples). The observation2 entries are irrelevant for filtering.
So in the above example it would end up looking like:

```
sample observation1 observation2
    sample1A 10 x
    sample1A 20 x
    sample1B 7 h
    sample1B 22 s
    sample2A 11 g
    sample2A 14 g
    sample2A 20 h
    sample2B 30 t
    sample2B 40 a
    sample2B 50 h
```

The previous solution (below) worked when there were only single observations associated with each sample, but now each sample can have multiple rows of observations and I only want to exlude the rows where observation 1 matched between a samplexA and samplexB.

```
data %>%
  group_by(grp = substr(sample, 1, nchar(sample)-1)) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(observation1)>1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%  
  select(sampleID, pos, grp)
```

Please let me know if I can clarify the question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a modification of your code. We can `group_by` two columns and count the number of each group, and filter for group counts that are equal to 1.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>% 
  group_by(grp = substr(sample, 1, nchar(sample) - 1), observation1) %>%
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%  
  select(-grp)

dt2
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     sample observation1 observation2
      <chr>        <int>        <chr>
 1 sample1A           10            x
 2 sample1A           20            x
 3 sample1B            7            h
 4 sample1B           22            s
 5 sample2A           11            g
 6 sample2A           14            g
 7 sample2A           20            h
 8 sample2B           30            t
 9 sample2B           40            a
10 sample2B           50            h
```

#### Data

```
dt <- read.table(text = "sample observation1 observation2
sample1A 10 x
                 sample1A 15 y
                 sample1A 20 x
                 sample1B 7 h
                 sample1B 15 a
                 sample1B 22 s
                 sample2A 10 g
                 sample2A 11 g
                 sample2A 14 g
                 sample2A 20 h
                 sample2B 10 a
                 sample2B 30 t
                 sample2B 40 a
                 sample2B 50 h",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```